# Create a dictionary with list items as keys and indices as values?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
s =['Hello','World','Hello','World']
l = list()
for x,y in enumerate(s):
    l.append((y,x))
```

The output I got is `[('Hello', 0), ('World', 1), ('Hello', 2), ('World', 3)]`

But I want

```
Hello-[0,2]
World-[1,3]
```

Comment: Do you mean you want a `dict` containing `{'Hello': [0, 2], 'World': [1, 3]}`?

Comment: Basically want to convert this into dictionary where Hello and World are my keys and their corresponding values are 0,2 and 1,3

Comment: Yes you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dictionary:

```
d = {}
for i, v in enumerate(s):
    if v in d:
        d[v].append(i)
    else:
        d[v] = [i]

d
# {'Hello': [0, 2], 'World': [1, 3]}
```

Comment: Here d[v] =[i] that means that [] is for list right?

Comment: Correct. if the word is first met, then create a list containing the corresponding index for the key.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is a perfect fit for this case (see also the answer of @mhawke) :

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)
for idx, item in enumerate(s):
    dd[item].append(idx)
```

Then convert this to a plain dictionary again:

```
>>> dict(dd)
{'Hello': [0, 2], 'World': [1, 3]}
```

---

I recently created a package containing a function that could be used as alternative [`iteration_utilities.groupedby`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/groupedby.html):

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import groupedby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> s =['Hello','World','Hello','World']
>>> groupedby(enumerate(s), key=itemgetter(1), keep=itemgetter(0))
{'Hello': [0, 2], 'World': [1, 3]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict) of lists:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
s = ['Hello','World','Hello','World']
for index, key in enumerate(s):
    d[key].append(index)

>>> print(d)
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'World': [1, 3], 'Hello': [0, 2]})
>>> print(dict(d))    # convert to a std dictionary
{'World': [1, 3], 'Hello': [0, 2]}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can also be done using a fairly simple dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> s =['Hello','World','Hello','World']
>>> d = {k: [pos for pos, el in enumerate(s) if el == k] for k in set(s)}
>>> d
{'World': [1, 3], 'Hello': [0, 2]}
>>>
```

This works by making keys using each *unique* element in the list `s`(which `set(s)` does), and getting the index of each of the unique elements(which the list comprehension does).